# PHP Curl setting the headers same

Tags: php, curl, header

How to make the headers same using PHP? I want to set the headers same while sending request from cURL. Basically, i am able to access a url by typing in the browser. But while using PHP cURL, am not able to access the page. So, maybe making the headers same can solve this.

Headers while sending actual request:

```
Request Line:  GET /jlp.cgi?Flag=Html_Data&LogType=0&Dummy=1341550112739 HTTP/1.1

Host: <abc>

Proxy-Connection:  Keep Alive

Cookie: iR=548729
```

There is no such field as `Connection` and `Referer` in the original request.
All the other fields (`User-Agent`, `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Encoding`) are same in both requests.

Headers when sending from cURL:

```
Request Line: GET /curlexp2.php?address=http%3A%2F%2F10.128.58.200%2Fjlp.cgi%3FFlag%3DHtml_Data%26LogType%3D0%26Dummy%3D1341550112739&submit=Log+In HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost

Connection: Keep Alive

Referer: http://localhost/exp2.php
```

There is no such field as `Proxy-Connection` and `Cookie` in this cURL request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make headers same as WHAT? The question is not clear.

Comment: Headers sent while using cURL should be same as those when the actual request i sent on the browser when i type in the URL.

Comment: not familiar enough with curl, but could you do: "require_once('head.php');" and then write the head.php document to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

use php's curl_setopt function and set the required header contents as an array.

```
curl_setopt(
 cur_resource,
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
 array(
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Content-Length: " . strlen($data),
  "Referrer": "...",
 )
);
```

Comment: @webbandit  When i do 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
I get this information: HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Date: SUN, 06 JUL 2012 04:42:42 GMT 
Server: CANON HTTP Server Ver2.21 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

So now what do i need to do..just maybe write 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Date: SUN, 06 JUL 2012 04:42:40 GMT", 'Server: CANON HTTP Server Ver2.21','Transfer-Encoding: chunked ')); ??

I tried this but still not working. Wht am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have to set each header as separate key-pair in array like array('Date' => 'SUN, 06 JUL 2012 04:42:40 GMT', 'Server' => 'CANON HTTP Server Ver2.21'); ... But most of headers you are trying to redefine are self-generated, you shouldn't replace them.

Comment: your arguments should be passed as an array of hash as pointed out by @webbandit

Comment: I did as said by @webbandit.('Date' => 'SUN, 06 JUL 2012 04:42:40 GMT', 'Server' => 'CANON HTTP Server Ver2.21'); But not able to  get any output. I have another doubt. What values should I put in the HTTPHEADER array? Is it those returned by CURLOPT_HEADER, or should i put the headers which i got when sending the actual request(which i got from HTTPFox) ??